# How to make an application think it is running a different version?

Tags: macos, applications

I own an application which, let's say, is version 7.2.6. I would like to make it think it is 7.2.8 when it goes to check. Is there anything I can change in a plist or files alike?

Comment: There is an Info.plist in the application.APP directory. But the application may not necessarily read the version number from there.

Comment: This has all the hallmarks of an X-Y problem. What are you hoping to achieve -- stopping updates?

Comment: Hi, I found and changed those however the app does not read it from there. The app offers people product which is already *downloaded/part of it* only made available upon update—however the update is just to get customers to move over as part of a patch, so I hypothesize that if I get it to think it is 7.2.8 when it checks, it'll make the content available to me. Think this is possible? Thanks for the replies.